# Button doesn't work when Appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

I am creating a window-oriented operating-system-ish application with jQuery.  When one window is clicked, it appends itself to the parent element, visually placing it on top of any other windows.  However, if there is a button inside the window, it won't let me click it until after the window is appended to the parent element, meaning I have to click it a second time.  Does anyone know why?

Here is my site: http://faithserve.com/jOS/v2/

On the site, clicking the test button should do `console.log("test")`.

The code is fairly complicated, but the appending script is basically this:

```
$(this.element).on("mousedown",function(e){
  thisWindow.app.menubar.display();
  if (!$(thisWindow.element).is(':last-child')) {
    $("#desktop").append(thisWindow.element);
  }
});
```

**Edit**

Since the link to my site above may end up being fixed or down in the future, here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/QhZr6/1/

Comment: The problem is that the code you show doesn't seem to be where is the error.

Comment: what is the .element?

Comment: What browser are you using? I was able to click on it as you mentioned using Firefox (latest)

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's a workaround to make the button work even when the mousedown event is appending it to the parent element.  The button does work, but only when you click it the second time after focusing the window it's in.  I'm in Chrome.  And you're right, it works in Firefox for me too.  Is this just a Chrome thing?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this might not be the most elegant solution but you could try something like this:

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("#message").html($("#message").html() + $(this).attr("id"));
});

$(".win").on("mousedown", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#con").append($this);
    }, 100);
});
```

**Edit:**
 It's recommended that you use `.on("click", function() {...} )` to bind event handlers to objects

Updated jsFiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/QhZr6/7/).